# Como executar código antes de começar a mudar orientação?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

Estou querendo saber se existe algum evento ou forma de executar um pedaço de código antes de acontecer a trocar de orientação no Windows Phone. Meu problema é que eu preciso fechar um `MenuFlyout` antes de trocar a orientação, caso contrário o aplicativo quebra. Alguém sabe contornar esse problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu faço algo semelhante. Quando a orientação da página é alterada eu fecho um painel em minha aplicação. Faço isso no evento disparado quando a orientação do aparelho muda.

```
public MainPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   this.OrientationChanged += OnOrientationChanged;
}

private void OnOrientationChanged(object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
{
   var orientação = e.Orientation;
}
```

[image: PageOrientation]

Veja a documentação [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207002(v=vs.105).aspx)

### EDIT

O Windows Phone não tem um evento com um nome fácil de vocÊ identificar que indique que este evento será disparado antes que a orientação da tela seja trocada, mas existe este evento.

O evento BeginLayoutChanged é disparado antes da orientação do telefone ser alterada.

```
BeginLayoutChanged += (o, args) => MessageBox.Show("Antes de Mudar");
OrientationChanged += (o, args) => MessageBox.Show("Depois de Mudar");
```

Mais informações sobre o evento [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage.beginlayoutchanged%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Alguns problemas: Eu sei que eu não falei, mas é windows phone 8.1 RT, ele só serve pro silverlight. Ainda sim, mesmo se fosse o caso, esse código é executado posteriormente a troca de orientação. :/

Comment: Veja o update da resposta, por favor.